# How to decode JSON Array with different objects with Codable in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I have a JSON which consist of a top object then an array which consist of different JSON Objects. I want to decode this json with minimal struct and without optional variables. If I can achieve, I also want to design a struct which handles all of the array objects via writing only Its relevant struct.

I'll try to simplify the example

[image: JSON Image]

As You can see in the image both "Id", "Token", "ServicePublicKey" are different JSON objects. Whole of my backend returns in this architecture of JSON. **What I want to achive** is that one struct as a wrapper and struct for (Id, ServicePublicKey, Token etc..). At the end when there is a new type coming from JSON, I need to write only relevant struct and add some code inside wrapper.

**My Question is that:** How can I parse this JSON without any optional variable?

**How I try to parse it:**

```
struct Initialization: Decodable {
var error: BunqError? //TODO: Change this type to a right one
var id: Int?
var publicKey: String?
var token: Token?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case error = "Error"
    case data = "Response"
    case Id = "Id"
    case id = "id"
    case ServerPublicKey = "ServerPublicKey"
    case Token = "Token"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    error = nil
    if let errorArray = try container.decodeIfPresent([BunqError].self, forKey: .error) {
        if !errorArray.isEmpty {
            error = errorArray[0]
        }
    }
    if let unwrappedResponse = try container.decodeIfPresent([Response<Id>].self, forKey: .data) {
        print(unwrappedResponse)
    }
}
}
struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
let responseModel: T?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case Id = "Id"
    case ServerPublicKey = "ServerPublicKey"
    case Token = "Token"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    switch "\(T.self)"
    {
    case CodingKeys.Id.rawValue:
        self.responseModel = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .Id)
        break;
    case CodingKeys.ServerPublicKey.rawValue:
        self.responseModel = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .ServerPublicKey)
        break;
    default:
        self.responseModel = nil
        break;
    }
}
}

struct Id: Decodable {
let id: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
}
}

struct ServerPublicKey: Decodable {
let server_public_key: String
}
struct Token: Decodable {
let created: String
let updated: String
let id: Int
let token: String
}
```

**Json Example:**

```
    {
  "Response" : [
    {
      "Id" : {
        "id" : 123456
      }
    },
    {
      "Token" : {
        "token" : "myToken",
        "updated" : "2020-01-11 13:55:43.397764",
        "created" : "2020-01-11 13:55:43.397764",
        "id" : 123456
      }
    },
    {
      "ServerPublicKey" : {
        "server_public_key" : "some key"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Question is: How to get the nth element of a JSON Array when Decoding with Codable in Swift?

Comment: I updated my post. That is my proper question :) Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What I want to achive is that one struct as a wrapper and struct for (Id, ServicePublicKey, Token etc..).
>   At the end when there is a new type coming from JSON, I need to write only relevant struct and add some code inside wrapper.
>   My Question is that: How can I parse this JSON without any optional variable?

First of all I totally agree with your idea.
When decoding a JSON we should always aim to

- no optionals (as long as this is guaranteed by the backend)
- easy extendibility

### Let's start

So given this JSON

```
let data = """
    {
        "Response": [
            {
                "Id": {
                    "id": 123456
                }
            },
            {
                "Token": {
                    "token": "myToken",
                    "updated": "2020-01-11 13:55:43.397764",
                    "created": "2020-01-11 13:55:43.397764",
                    "id": 123456
                }
            },
            {
                "ServerPublicKey": {
                    "server_public_key": "some key"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

### ID Model

```
struct ID: Decodable {
    let id: Int
}
```

### Token Model

```
struct Token: Decodable {
    let token: String
    let updated: String
    let created: String
    let id: Int
}
```

### ServerPublicKey Model

```
struct ServerPublicKey: Decodable {
    let serverPublicKey: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case serverPublicKey = "server_public_key"
    }
}
```

### Result Model

```
struct Result: Decodable {

    let response: [Response]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response = "Response"
    }

    enum Response: Decodable {

        enum DecodingError: Error {
            case wrongJSON
        }

        case id(ID)
        case token(Token)
        case serverPublicKey(ServerPublicKey)

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id = "Id"
            case token = "Token"
            case serverPublicKey = "ServerPublicKey"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            switch container.allKeys.first {
            case .id:
                let value = try container.decode(ID.self, forKey: .id)
                self = .id(value)
            case .token:
                let value = try container.decode(Token.self, forKey: .token)
                self = .token(value)
            case .serverPublicKey:
                let value = try container.decode(ServerPublicKey.self, forKey: .serverPublicKey)
                self = .serverPublicKey(value)
            case .none:
                throw DecodingError.wrongJSON
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Let's decode!

We can finally decode your JSON

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

### Output

And this is the output

```
Result(response: [
    Result.Response.id(
        Result.Response.ID(
            id: 123456
        )
   ),
   Result.Response.token(
        Result.Response.Token(
            token: "myToken",
            updated: "2020-01-11 13:55:43.397764",
            created: "2020-01-11 13:55:43.397764",
            id: 123456)
    ),
    Result.Response.serverPublicKey(
        Result.Response.ServerPublicKey(
            serverPublicKey: "some key"
        )
    )
])
```

### Date Decoding

I leave the date decoding to you as homework ;-)

## UPDATE

This additional part should answer to your comment

> Can we store variables like id, serverPublicKey inside Result struct
>   without Response array. I mean instead of ResponseArray can we just
>   have properties? I think It need a kind of mapping but I can't figure
>   out.

Yes, I think we can.

We need to add one more struct to the ones already described above.

Here it is

```
struct AccessibleResult {

    let id: ID
    let token: Token
    let serverPublicKey: ServerPublicKey

    init?(result: Result) {

        typealias ComponentsType = (id: ID?, token: Token?, serverPublicKey: ServerPublicKey?)

        let components = result.response.reduce(ComponentsType(nil, nil, nil)) { (res, response) in
            var res = res
            switch response {
            case .id(let id): res.id = id
            case .token(let token): res.token = token
            case .serverPublicKey(let serverPublicKey): res.serverPublicKey = serverPublicKey
            }
            return res
        }

        guard
            let id = components.id,
            let token = components.token,
            let serverPublicKey = components.serverPublicKey
        else { return nil }

        self.id = id
        self.token = token
        self.serverPublicKey = serverPublicKey
    }
}
```

This AccessibleResult struct has an initialiser which receives a Result value and tries to populated its 3 properties

```
let id: ID
let token: Token
let serverPublicKey: ServerPublicKey
```

If everything goes fine, I mean if the input `Result` contains at least an `ID`, a `Token` and a `ServerPublicKey` then the `AccessibleResponse` is initialised, otherwise the init fails and nil` is returned.

### Test

```
if
    let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data),
    let accessibleResult = AccessibleResult(result: result) {
        print(accessibleResult)
}
```

Comment: Wow. What a great answer. Just one more question. Can we store variables like id, serverPublicKey inside Result struct without Response array. I mean instead of ResponseArray can we just have properties? I think It need a kind of mapping but I can't figure out.

Comment: @EmreÖnder Got it, will answer to this new question later today.

Comment: I'm also trying things but all of the tries forwards me to creating unnecessary structs that is used for decoding only. Btw, I'll give bounty to you when it is open :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very clear and understandable.